# Sring actuator system status missing scheduler data when schedulers are added programatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Java 11, Spring Boot. I had my schedulers running with `@Scheduled` annotation and they appeared in Actuator page: `#/administration/systemstatus` automatically. But since now I have to provide possibility to schedule a task forcibly from UI I have to invoke `schedule` operation on `TaskScheduler` for such task for current time and after it ends, I have to again schedule such task according to some cron expression from application.properties (because schedule operations changes the scheduled time and I tasks generally have to be working on specified cron times and only sometimes will be additionally triggered by user form UI). That lead me to write my own scheduling component as I found it impossible to do all of this with @Schedule annotation. But as a side effect I don't have data about tasks and their cron expressions in actuator systemstatus. Below is the code, I include only a part that adds tasks to scheduler when application is deployed. I am not adding reschedule operations. Do u know how to repair the actuator data ?

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyTaskService {

    private final TaskScheduler scheduler;
    private final List<CustomTask> taskList; //runnable tasks
    private final RunningTasksFutureHolder runningTasksFutureHolder;

    public MyTaskService(TaskScheduler scheduler,
                               List<CustomTask> taskList,
                               RunningTasksFutureHolder runningTasksFutureHolder) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
        this.taskList = taskList;
        this.runningTasksFutureHolder = runningTasksFutureHolder;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterLoad() {
        askList.forEach(this::addTaskToScheduler);
    }

    public void addTaskToScheduler(CustomTask task) {
    //here tasks are added to scheduler and they are not visible in actuator
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTask = scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger(task.getCronExpression()));
        runningTasksFutureHolder.add(task.getTaskType(), scheduledTask);
    }

}





@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        //do nothing here
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        scheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        scheduler.initialize();
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` rather than calling `TaskScheduler` directly. For the cron task the corresponding method is `addCronTask()`.

References:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8831#issuecomment-575886881
- https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-cron-task-with-spring-boot-scheduler

Comment: This is good idea however I am now struggling with finding a way to remove tasks registered in this way. As soon as I will find it, I will mark it as a correct answer. But the ScheduledTaskRegistrar doesn provide remove task operation or reschedule operation. And I cannot add multiple tasks of the same type - they cannot be run in pararell.

Comment: Well you have `getCronTaskList()`/ `getScheduledTasks()` and `getScheduler()` so it looks like you can cancel any registered task. Although this will make the registered tasks data in this registrar stale. I don't think this was meant as a full scheduled tasks administration interface in the first place.

Comment: Yeah,.. I cannot cancel some running tasks because I could make some mess in filesystem  for example for tasks working with filesystem. So my task can have running property which says that it is running. If it such task is not runninng currently, I am taking it from getScheduledTasks() using ScheduledTask.cancel() method, then schedule it immediatelly using TaskScheduler and then when this immediate infocation is finished I am againg using registry addCronTask to activate this task accoring to cron expression again.

Comment: Cancelled task is always present it getScheduledTasks() so I am trying to understand it , can and should I invoke taskRegistrar.addCronTask() again after immediate invocation is finished.

Comment: When you cancel a cron task from the registrar it's removed from the scheduler but stays in the registrar's internal `cronTasks` list. You can update it manually using `getCronTaskList()`/`setCronTasksList()`.

Comment: After cancelling it is not running again, I am still looking what could I update to make it running againg according to cron expression

Comment: Use `scheduleCronTask()` to schedule it back